# Sudden drop observed in the MySQL Update Query

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-update

I have profiled the performance of MySQL update query.After the steady state   a sudden drop was observed in the throughput graph. I have redone the tests several times. I found that, the sudden drop place is not the same point for the same scenario. It varies time to time. I wonder this is happening because of caching in the buffer pool? I did the same tests using MsSQL I couldn't find this problem with that. Please help me with this confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance (for big tables) is all about disk hits.  And tricks to mitigate such.

Need more details -- such as `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW TABLE STATUS` and the `UPDATE`.  How severe is the drop in performance?  How big is the buffer_pool?  What fraction of RAM it it?  But here are some general answers.

The **"Change buffer"** is a technique for caching writes to indexes.  `INSERTs` and `DELETEs` need to eventually update all non-unique indexes.  Also, `UPDATEs` need to do likewise if an indexed column is changed.  Such changes are collected in the "change buffer", which is in the buffer_pool.  By default, 25% of the buffer_pool is dedicated to such.

After some number of modifications, the change buffer gets full.  At this point, read-modify-write cycles are needed to update the BTrees that contain the indexes.  This *may* be visible as a slowdown in throughput.

Meanwhile, what about queries that need the indexes that are not yet updated?  Not a problem.  The CB is checked as needed.  (Extra CPU cycles to avoid I/O -- usually a win.)

**UUIDs** are terrible for performance -- sometimes the have the "fell off a cliff" syndrone.  The reason is how random they are, hence how useless any caching is -- once the table (or uuid index) is bigger than can entirely fit in the buffer_pool.  A UUID column is usually declared `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY`), hence needs to be checked immediately on `INSERT`.  That is, it cannot be delayed in the Change Buffer.

If you are building a table with UUIDs, for a long time, it can all be cached in the buffer_pool, and throughput is nice.  But eventually the table/index gets too big and necessary I/O creeps in.  When the table is 20 times as big as can be cached, only 1/20 of the actions can be found in cache.

What about **MSSql**?  Different vendors use different techniques to tackle the main performance killer: disk.  I don't know what Oracle, etc, do; but it is possibly different, and probably hits some other variant of a brick wall due to UUIDs or cache being full.

(There may be other explanations for what you are seeing.)